# Find DL in given paths

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis

[image]
I wanna just say that DL is the tangential vector at every point, but I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant to post this on [math.SE]

Comment: That's correct but I guess that the exercise wants you to express $\vec{dl}$ along paths 1, 2, 3 using standard basis vectors.

Comment: You just need to calculate the projections into x and y of the path (a right tringle with hypotenuse 2)